# ROS CPP equivalent of Python subprocess.call() with shell=True

Tags: python, c++, ros

The following code snippet works fine in ROS Indigo (Python 2.7)-

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["rosnode", "kill", "my_node"], shell=True)
```

However, I am looking for ROS CPP equivalent of above function. The `system` command isn't working since the specified command is supposed to be executed through the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.system()` method that's it.

Before, I used this method in a ROS package, as following to publish a topic manually:

```
system("rostopic pub -1 /tilt_scan_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 -- 0.0");
```

In your situation will be:

```
system("rosnode kill <your-node-name>");
```